# In Vue 2, how can i pass a variable between two components? Is this only possible with parent-child components?

Tags: vue.js, events, vuejs2, components, parent-child

I would like to know how to transfer data between two components that have no parent-child relationship.

is  this even possible? If so, how would a snipped look like?

Any input is appreciated, thanks a ton :)

Comment: You need to use some state management , for example most used [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Comment: These are javascript basics, also you didn't provide anything you have tried, which is a lack of studying in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to share.

If it needs reactivity, you can import&export a constant with a Vue.observable API.
If it doesn't need reactivity you can just import&export a constant.

These are Javascript basics really, it's framework agnostic.